# Where in the C++ Standard is it stated that a const rvalue reference doesn't bind to an lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

Where in the C++ Standard is it stated that a const rvalue reference doesn't bind to an lvalue?

For example the code below doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 10;

int f(const int&& j) { return j; }
int main()
{
    std::cout << f(i) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Probably nowhere. I don't think the standard lists all the things that don't bind to other things. The list would be quite large.

Comment: Is it surprising that the code doesn't compile? Why *should* it?

Comment: Not just a `const` rvalue, you can't bind an lvalue to an rvalue ref at all...

Comment: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the last bullet of [dcl.init.ref]/5 (quoting n3485):

> If `T1` [the type of the initialized reference] is reference-related to `T2` [the type of the initializer expression] and the reference is an rvalue reference,
>   the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue.

The cv-qualification is irrelevant in this case.

---

The first (main) bullet of /5 doesn't apply since the reference is not an lvalue reference:

> If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression [...]

The second (main) bullet point applies:

> Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), **or the reference shall be an rvalue reference**

[emphasis mine]

The first sub bullet point of this doesn't apply since the initializer is is not an xvalue or function prvalue and doesn't have class type.

The second sub-bullet-point is an unconditional "otherwise", so that last sub bullet point applies.

---

If the initializer is *not* reference-related to the referred type (`T1`), the example compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

double i = 10;

int f(const int&& j) { return j; }
int main()
{
    std::cout << f(i) << '\n';
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60dd62e3a3f4bd7)

Comment: I believe you mean the bullet point: "Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference." I tried to follow this bullet with no avail. I just couldn't find the case of const rvalue ref.

Comment: @user1042389 It's not mentioned specifically, but covered by a more general rule: An rvalue reference to a const type is an rvalue reference, so this bullet applies, and the second sub-bullet disallows binding an lvalue to a reference-related rvalue reference.

Comment: You said you are quoting N3485, but this as I recall is post-C++11. I'm quoting N3337.

Comment: I'm using N3485 since that contains more proposed resolutions to defects in C++11 but no C++1y extensions yet. The three big compilers I know (MSVC, clang++, g++) incorporate some of those proposed resolutions in their C++11 modes.

Comment: But does that mean that C++11 doesn't cover this? Hard to believe this is the case.

Comment: I just skimmed through the rules in n3337, and they seem to be equivalent in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

`[C++11: 8.5.3/3]` lists how initialisers for references work; what you're looking for is there. It's too exhaustive to quote here verbatim, though.